# Algorithmic Composition: generative vs transformative algorith

Tags: algorithms, terminology

What's the difference between **generative** and **transformative** algorithms in relation to algorithmic composition of music?

As I understand the basic idea of the algorithms themselves, generative uses past candidate values (output becomes input) as progenitors (parents) for the next output, i.e. by combining them under certain conditions.

Transformative algorithms use environmental factors only to determine how to change the existing input.

However I've read that generative music as created by Brian Eno can use environmental factors and a single candidate input value, transforming it based on stored environmental factors.

I am struggling to understand what the difference is since there seems to be no universal agreement on what constitutes generative.

Comment: Bear in mind that Brian Eno (like any other composer) is free to do whatever he wants. When we're teaching, we often divide things up into little compartments but, when things are implemented in the real world, hybrid approaches are often used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *generative* algorithm tries to generate a new song out of nothing.

A *transformative* algorithm takes one song $s$ as input, and tries to produce a new song $s'$ by making some changes to $s$.